# How do I enable page exception output in nopcommerce MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce

Currently, if there is ANY KIND OF ERROR in a view or route in nopcommerce MVC, I get alien unicode text, meaning it looks like you are viewing binary output via text. I had to rewrite this question because it was said to not be specific enough although this is just another way to say the exact same thing so not sure what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is fixed in version 2.30. Or simply apply changeset [d21c5993c77f](http://nopcommerce.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/changes/d21c5993c77f) and [dd416ab78db1](http://nopcommerce.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/changes/dd416ab78db1). Let me know if it helped

Comment: Ahhhhhhhh you are the creator of Nop. :)  ha ha ha ha. Its no wonder you know this one. Good man.